# Выдает ошибку при добавлении <aop:config>

Tags: java, spring, aop

Есть такой рабочий конфиг:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
            <!-- Создаем бин с вызовом конструктора -->
<bean id="duke" class="springTest.Juggler">
    <constructor-arg value="15" />
</bean>
<bean id="poeticDuke" class="springTest.PoeticJuggler">
    <constructor-arg value="15" />
    <constructor-arg ref="sonnet29" />
</bean>

<!-- Тоже самое, но без конструктора -->
<bean id="sonnet29" class="springTest.Sonnet29" />

<!-- Определяем статический метод который должен вызываться для создания 
    экземпляра вместо конструктора -->
<bean id="theStage" class="springTest.Stage" factory-method="getInstance" />

<!-- Создаем новый экземпляр билета на концерт при каждом обращении -->
<bean id="ticket" class="springTest.Ticket" scope="prototype" />

<!-- Определяем методы(init-method destroy-method) при создании и уничтожении 
    компонента -->
<bean id="auditorium" class="springTest.Auditorium" init-method="turnOnLights"
    destroy-method="turnOffLights" />

<!-- Как и в <constructor-arg> внедряем аргументы через конструктор, только 
    <property> вызывает метод и передает ему значение -->
<!-- В данном случае мы вызываем метод setSong() и передаем ему "Jingle 
    Bells" -->
<bean id="kenny" class="springTest.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="Jingle Bells" />
</bean>

<!-- Создаем бин для Инструментов -->
<bean id="saxophone" class="springTest.Saxophone" />
<bean id="piano" class="springTest.Piano" />
<bean id="guitar" class="springTest.Guitar" />
<bean id="cymbal" class="springTest.Cymbal" />
<bean id="harmonica" class="springTest.Harmonica" />

<!-- и для аудитории -->
<bean id="audience" class="springTest.Audience" />

<!-- Вызываем метод setIntrument() и передаем ему ссылку на класс Saxophone/Piano -->
<bean id="kenny2" class="springTest.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="Jingle Bells" />
    <property name="instrument" ref="saxophone" />
</bean>

<bean id="kenny3" class="springTest.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="Jingle Bells" />
    <property name="instrument" ref="piano" />
</bean>


<!-- Кенни брезгливый и мы объявим его саксофон как внутренний компонент(он 
    теперь личный для Кенни) -->
<bean id="kenny4" class="springTest.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="Jingle Bells" />
    <property name="instrument">
        <bean class="springTest.Saxophone" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Тоже самое для Дюка, но вместо <property> используем <constructor-arg> -->
<bean id="duke2" class="springTest.PoeticJuggler">
    <constructor-arg value="15" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="springTest.Sonnet29" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Хенк человек-оркестр, ему нужно передать коллекцию инструментов с помощью 
    <list> аналогично можем использовать <set> -->
<bean id="hankCollection" class="springTest.OneManBandWithCollection">
    <property name="instruments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="guitar" />
            <ref bean="cymbal" />
            <ref bean="harmonica" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Теперь Хенк использует не Collection, а Map -->
<bean id="hankMap" class="springTest.OneManBandWithMap">
    <property name="instruments">
        <map>
            <entry key="GUITAR" value-ref="guitar" />
            <entry key="CYMBAL" value-ref="cymbal" />
            <entry key="HARMONICA" value-ref="harmonica" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Теперь Хенк использует не Collection или Map, а Properties -->
<bean id="hankProperties" class="springTest.OneManBandWithProperties">
    <property name="instruments">
        <props>
            <prop key="GUITAR">STRUM STRUM STRUM</prop>
            <prop key="CYMBAL">CRASH CRASH CRASH</prop>
            <prop key="HARMONICA">HUM HUM HUM</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Пробуем SpEL создаем Карла, который исполняет песню ту же самую что 
    и Кенни -->
<bean id="carl" class="springTest.Instrumentalist">
    <property name="song" value="#{kenny.song}" />
</bean>


<!-- Создаем абстрактный класс и наследуем его Васей и Петей, а Жора переопределяет 
    метод song -->
<bean id="baseSaxophonist" class="springTest.Instrumentalist"
    abstract="true">
    <property name="instrument" ref="saxophone" />
    <property name="song" value="Jingle Bells" />
</bean>

<bean id="Vasja" parent="baseSaxophonist" />
<bean id="Petja" parent="baseSaxophonist" />

<bean id="Zhora" parent="baseSaxophonist">
    <property name="song" value="Mary had a little lamb" />
</bean>


<!-- Фишка с наследованием которой нету в Джаве -->
<bean id="basePerformer" abstract="true">
    <property name="song" value="Somewhere Over the Rainbow" />
</bean>

<bean id="taylor" class="springTest.Vocalist" parent="basePerformer" />
<bean id="stevie" class="springTest.Instrumentalist" parent="basePerformer">
    <property name="instrument" ref="guitar" />
</bean>

<!-- Замещаем метод getContents -->
<bean id="harry" class="springTest.Magician">
    <property name="magicBox" ref="magicBox" />
    <property name="magicWords" value="Bippity boppity boo" />
</bean>
<bean id="magicBox" class="springTest.MagicBoxImpl">
    <replaced-method name="getContents" replacer="tigerReplacer" />
</bean>
<bean id="tigerReplacer" class="springTest.TigerReplacer" />


    <!-- Определяем аспект Audience с использованием элементов настройки Spring AOP -->

</beans>
```

Если в самом конце, после

> "Определяем аспект Audience с использованием элементов настройки
>   Spring AOP"

вставить этот код:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="audience">
    <aop:pointcut id="performance" expression="execution(* com.springinaction.springidol.Performer.perform())" />
    <aop:before pointcut-ref="performance" method="takeSeats" />
    <aop:before pointcut-ref="performance" method="turnOffCellPhones" />
    <aop:after-returning pointcut-ref="performance" method="applaud" />
    <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="performance" method="demandRefund" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
    WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'duke' defined in class path resource [springTest/spring-idol.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at springTest.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:466)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:315)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:194)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getMethodMatcher(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:169)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.buildSafePointcut(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:187)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor.<init>(AspectJPointcutAdvisor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 27 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'duke' defined in class path resource [springTest/spring-idol.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at springTest.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor#0': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:275)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1139)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.findAdvisorBeans(BeanFactoryAdvisorRetrievalHelper.java:86)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:466)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:163)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:267)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:315)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:194)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getMethodMatcher(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:169)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.buildSafePointcut(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:187)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJPointcutAdvisor.<init>(AspectJPointcutAdvisor.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    ... 27 more
```

Как можно решить проблему?
П.С. Я новичок как в Java так и в Spring, а так же stackoverflow. Поправьте, если что не так сделал. Спасибо за ответы!

---

Исправил, теперь такая ошибка:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'carl' defined in class path resource [springTest/spring-idol.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'song' cannot be found on object of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at springTest.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'song' cannot be found on object of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.evaluateBeanDefinitionString(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.doEvaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:255)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.evaluate(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 6): Property or field 'song' cannot be found on object of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.access$000(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:46)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference$AccessorLValue.getValue(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:372)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое последнее исключение в стек-трейсе:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.springinaction.springidol.Performer [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]

Нет ни одного бина класса `com.springinaction.springidol.Performer`, но вы пытаетесь применить к ним аспект.

Очевидно, вы заменили для всех классов пакет из книги `com.springinaction.springidol` на свой `springTest`, а в pointcut-е про это забыли. Так должно завестись:

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="audience">
    <aop:pointcut id="performance" expression="execution(* springTest.Performer.perform())" />
    <aop:before pointcut-ref="performance" method="takeSeats" />
    <aop:before pointcut-ref="performance" method="turnOffCellPhones" />
    <aop:after-returning pointcut-ref="performance" method="applaud" />
    <aop:after-throwing pointcut-ref="performance" method="demandRefund" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: Исправил, теперь новые ошибки. В комментарий не влезает код, напишу отдельным постом.

Answer (score 0):

Добавил в интерфейс Performer недостающие геттеры и сеттеры. Теперь компилируется, НО мне так же пришлось добавить ко всем классам которые использует интерфейс Performer недостающие методы. Пример:

```
@Override
public void setSong(String song) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public String getSong() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

Вопрос, можно ли так делать вообще? Что-то мне кажется что это не очень хорошо...

Comment: Вообще, у класса `Instrumentalist` и так есть методы `setSong` и `getSong`. Ваш код точно соответствует книге?

Comment: Да, но кроме Instrumentalist,  интерфейс Performer использует так-же Juggler, Magician и многие другие, к ним я и добавлял эти методы

Comment: Но у вас ошибка на бине `carl` и его поле `song`. А не у всех Performer -ов.

Comment: Перепроверил код по книжке, вроде бы всё как надо написано. Незнаю почему, но код работает. Подсказку кстати я нашел на англо-язычном stackoverflow, там была такая же проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Прочитывая эту же книгу (Spring in Action), наткнулся на такую же проблему.

Разумеется, не нужно трогать интерфейс.

Проблема заключается в том,что у нас не один компонент связан с интерфейсом Performer. Поэтому до нашего класса, где мы определяем контекст и вытягиваем конкретный бин, берётся неограниченный срез множества точек сопряжения, другими словами, берутся все компоненты, связанные с интерфейсом. 
Решение довольно простое: нужно ограничить срез множества точек сопряжения с помощью указателя bean():

```
 <aop:pointcut id="performance" expression="execution(* springTest.Performer.perform()) and bean(имя вашего бина)" />
```

Ну и по книге:

> Это определение говорит, что совет аспекта должен применяться к вызовам метода Performer.perform(), но только внутри компонента
>   с идентификатором "имя вашего бина".